# Community shouldn't poke old questions asked by a user whose account has disappeared

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-user, deleted-accounts

The following topic was poked up in [`[javascript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) by user -1, the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

[How to overlay a small page on a html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502575/how-to-overlay-a-small-page-on-a-html-page)

However, it really doesn't make any sense to me to answer a question asked by a user whose account is deleted/non-existing. You've zero chance that it could ever get accepted and because the question would remain unaccepted, the topic would be poked up some time later again and again.

I'd vote for stopping Community from poking questions asked by a non-existing user.

Comment: I think the algorithm is to poke [Unanswered](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) questions, not necessarily ones without an accepted answer.

Comment: @Bill: Hmm, thus questions with answers without any vote?

Comment: Yes, if an answer gets upvoted, that question is no longer considered "Unanswered."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's poked to the top, we might also want to *delete* it if it's bad.

So the "poking" is useful in this case, to churn the sediment so we can find both treasures and trash.

Comment: That, combined with the comment of Bill, makes indeed sense now. I namely didn't knew that only unanswered questions with unvoted answers got poked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Why not? While they user may be gone, that doesn't mean that there question has become irrelevant.. there could still be others with the same problem, and it would be useful to them if they could find an answer for it.

The point of the site is to benefit the community, which means even if the original asker is not around, that doesn't mean that the community wont benefit from someone answering the question.

Comment: Those could just ask a new question.

Comment: Not to mention the people finding the question through google and not finding an answer. And @BalusC no they could not, it would be closed as duplicate of the unanswered question.

Comment: @BalusC - What would be the point of them re-asking a question that was asked by another user...? ("Because we deleted it because the user left" - problem solved by *not* deleting it)

Comment: @Kop: If a question is unanswered, how is it worth being a valuable duplicate?